# Initializing a temporary variable in linked list python

Tags: python, variables, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In python, linked list creation includes creating two classes, one is the **class** node and the other one is the **class** `linkedlist`.

In the **class** `linkedlist` , in the `__init__()` `self.head=None` is initiated.

but when inserting an element at the end of the linked list we use temporary **variables** like `temp`.can we initialize `temp in __init__()`?

```
class Node(self):

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
class LinkedList(self):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
    def append(self,data):
        new=Node(data)
        if(head==None):
            self.head=new
        else:
            temp=self.head
            while(temp.next!=None):
                temp=temp.next
            temp.next=new


ll=LinkedList()
ll.append(1)
ll.append(2)
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: `temp` implies that it's temporary -- if it's temporary, you shouldn't make it a permanent part of every instance of your class.  You **can** do it but it's easier if variables are as short-lived as possible, because it means you don't have to keep track of them for as long.

Comment: You *could* make it an instance variable you initialize in `__init__`, but why would you want to? This seems like it *should* be a local variable.

Comment: `temp`'s role is as an implementation detail of the `append` algorithm; it doesn't represent any innate property of the list itself. `head`, on the other hand, is the "anchor" which keeps any nodes you create from being garbage collected: it fundamentally *is* your linked list.